# No entiendo bien, Flask host y puerto

Tags: python, flask

Estoy utilizando un servidor gratuito supuestamente vps hosting compartido....

No tienen los puertos abiertos y no puedo usar la ip (ejemplo escribir la ip:5000 en el navegador para ver flask)... no me dan servicio de ayuda tampoco....

He hecho un scanner de puertos para ver y me consigo con el 4848 entre otros... los otros me dice el terminal que no puedo usarlo porque están ocupados... (hace do flask run --port xxx en el terminal)

Entonces lo que hice en el app es poner host 0.0.0.0

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4848)
```

Cuando hago en la terminal python app.py
me sale esto...

```
Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:4848/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Es normal... pero cuando hago flask run me sale que está en la 127.0.0.1 puerto 5000

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Si hago

flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4848 obtengo lo que quiero...

```
Running on http://0.0.0.0:4848/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Pero en realidad no se si está en 127.0.0.1 o en 0.0.0.0 ...

Es por eso que no responde el chatbot?

https://intercongreso.vps.co.ve/tonib

Como soluciono esto para que responda el chatbot?

Se puede usar el dominio en vez del host?

Me refiero hacer algo como esta loquera...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(dominio='intercongreso.vps.co.ve', port:4848)
```

(Se que no se puede porque no lo veo por la red)

Gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 2):

Varias cosas previas:

- Conectando a la URL que proporcionas y examinando las cabeceras de respuesta se observa:

  ```
  server: Apache
  ```

  Es decir, las peticiones a esa URL las responde Apache (que es quien escucha en el puerto 443, que es el puerto al que el navegador se conecta por defecto ante una conexión https).

  Eso tiene sentido. Normalmente los servidores públicos tienen abierto sólo los puertos 443 (para https) y 80 (para http). Aún si lanzas tu aplicación flask en otro puerto, suele haber un cortafuegos que impide que un cliente externo pueda conectarse con ese puerto.
- La diferencia entre lanzar Flask en la IP `127.0.0.1` o `0.0.0.0` es que la `127.0.0.1` sólo es accesible desde clientes que se estén ejecutando en la misma máquina que Flask. En cambio la ip `0.0.0.0` es accesible desde fuera (a menos que un cortafuegos lo impida).

  Por otro lado "desde fuera" significa simplemente "desde fuera de esa máquina", pero no significa "desde internet". Es posible que la máquina esté en una subred privada, en cuyo caso podría ser accesible desde otras máquinas de esa subred, pero no desde el exterior. Esto en particular sucederá si la máquina está detrás de un NAT y no tiene IP pública.
- Si quisieras conectar a tu servidor que está escuchando, pongamos por caso, en el puerto 5000, en la URL tendrías que especificar ese número de puerto tras el nombre del host. Es decir: `http://intercongreso.vps.co.ve:5000`. En este caso deberías usar como protocolo http en vez de https (pues flask no soporta por defecto cifrado), y la ruta tras el 5000 ya dependería de qué rutas hayas implementado en tu aplicación flask.

  En todo caso probablemente la conexión no funcionará (acabará con un "el servidor no responde" tras un rato de espera), porque como dije antes habrá cortafuegos que impiden el acceso a ese puerto.

  Aún si el cortafuegos no lo impide, es posible que la máquina esté detrás de un NAT y no tenga IP pública. Entonces tampoco sería accesible. Es posible que tu servicio de hosting haya configurado el NAT para que redirija los puertos 80 y 443, de modo que Apache sí que sea accesible pero tu servidor Flask no.

Dicho todo lo anterior.

- El mecanismo estándar que deberías usar para hacer tu aplicación Flask accesible es configurar convenientemente Apache para que, ante ciertas URLs, en lugar de dar servicio el propio Apache, reenvíe la petición hacia otro puerto (por ejemplo el 5000 donde podría estar escuchando Flask), haciendo de *proxy reverso*.
- Ese mecanismo tiene muchas ventajas:

  - Ya que Flask sería accedido desde Apache, y ambos están en la misma máquina, no necesitas hacer que Flask escuche en 0.0.0.0. Puede escuchar en 127.0.0.1
  - Por la misma razón, no importa en qué puerto escuche Flask (con tal de que hayas configurado Apache para que reenvie a ese puerto)
  - El usuario no tiene que poner numeros de puerto raros en la URL, ya que habla con Apache (y es éste quien hace de intermediario con Flask)
  - La comunicación puede ser https, segura, pues es Apache quien maneja los certificados y el cifrado, y lo que le pasa a Flask ya va sin cifrar (evitando así tener que configurar Flask para tráfico https, que sería complejo).

Como ves todo son ventajas. El problema es que no sé cómo configurar Apache para que redirija a Flask, pues no suelo usar Apache sino nginx. No obstante seguro que encuentras por internet mucha información acerca de cómo hacerlo. Otra cosa es que tu proveedor de hosting te permita tocar la configuración de Apache...

Por último, si vas a poner el servicio "en producción", te recomendaría echar un vistazo a Gunicorn como servidor de aplicaciones, en lugar de usar el servidor de desarrollo que viene integrado con Flask. Gunicorn soporta más clientes simultáneos y es más eficiente. Si lo usas, el escenario sería análogo al antes descrito. Gunicorn escucharía en 127.0.0.1, puerto 5000 por ejemplo, y Apache le reenviaría las peticiones.

Comment: Amigo adulafia tremenda explicación... todavía estoy luchando con esto... ya instalé gunicorn.... estoy viendo como hacer con esto de Apache ... Gracias por tu extensa explicación amigo